# Google compute Engine, error al conectar remotamente al MySQL

Tags: base-de-datos, linux, google-cloud-platform

Tengo un error al crear acceso remoto al gestor de base de datos MySQL que esta alojado en una instancia en Google compute Engine

Tengo una instancia en **Google compute Engine** usando **Bitnami** en donde tengo una intancia de **MySql**, estoy tratando de conectarme remotamente, para lo cual cree un usuario en la base de datos de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'x.x.x.x';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

en donde `x.x.x.x` corresponde a la ip pública de mi instancia 
además abrí el puerto 3306 de la siguiente manera

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d x.x.x.x --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s X.X.X.X --sport 3306 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

pero al momento de ejecutar:

```
sudo nmap x.x.x.x
```

no me sale que el puerto 3306 este abierto, lo que necesito es conectarme remotamente desde **heidisql** y adicional necesito conectar la base de datos con **Google Data Studio**.

por favor necesito su ayuda llevo dos días intentando esto y me urge, agradecería su ayuda enormemente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta creando la regla de cortafuegos desde la consola de Google Cloud:

1. Ve a https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Selecciona "Ir al panel de control de Compute Engine"
3. Selecciona tu instancia
4. Selecciona la interfaz de red a configurar
5. En el panel de la derecha selecciona "Reglas de firewall"
6. Selecciona "Crear regla de firewall"
7. Asigna un nombre a la regla, en "Destinos" selecciona "Todas las instancias de la red", en "Intervalos de IP de fuente" pon 0.0.0.0/0 para permitir la conexión desde cualquier IP, en "Protocolos y puertos" selecciona "tcp" y pon 3306
8. Guarda la regla

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, realmente ese era el problema ya logre conectarme remotamente y además me conecte a Data Studio mil gracias